# SharedPreferences vs DB vs JSON

Tags: android, process, preferences, shared, synchronized

I have a set of preferences that I would like to share between processes in my application.  However android does not support that at this time.  I've read that you could use synchronized but I can find no examples of this.  So what would be the best work around for this?  Maybe there is a way I am unaware of.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you have multiple applications that you are sharing preferences between or just one application that creates different processes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running separate processes? Separate processes run in separate JVMs and need to be specially configured to happen: see [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Processes).

Since processes run in separate JVMs you can not simply share data via common java objects (and synchronize access with `synchronized`). You can only do this when you run multiple threads, which run in same JVM.

You can share data between processes with [Inter Process Communication](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#IPC).

Of course you can also share data via Shared Preferences or a file, but this does not notify the other process about the new data, so you can hardly call this 'communication'. Also this approach has problems with synchronization (reading and writing at the same time.)

Comment: Yup, I'm in separate processes, because of how critical it is that the services stay alive (there are 2 for the application) they must run in separate processes (as defined in the Manifest). I know about IPC and AIDL but was just checking if there was something hidden that I was unaware of.  Thanks though